# Sifting a list of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by size

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ say `{{1,2}, {2,3}, {0.2,4},{0.6,81}}` is there some way to extract the elements of the list with the condition `Abs[x], Abs[y] <5`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two options:

```
Select[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {0.2, 4}, {0.6, 81}}, And @@ Thread[Abs[#] < {5, 5}] &]
Cases[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {0.2, 4}, {0.6, 81}}, {x_, y_} /; Abs[x] < 5 && Abs[y] < 5]

(* Out: {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {0.2, 4}} *)
```

Comment: The `Select` can be simplified to `Select[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {0.2, 4}, {0.6, 81}}, 
 And @@ Thread[Abs[#] < 5] &]`

Comment: @BobHanlon That's true, but I left it in the more verbose two-value form in case the OP later needs to have different thresholds for each variable.